# Get list of second elements from an XML file using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml file and i wanted to read only the second level elements from the list. For example i want to have a list of only the vehicles such as follows

Vehicle Number: "180", Type : "BUS"
Vehicle Number: "190", Type: "BUS"
.......
.......

This is my xml format

```
<departures> 
 <station> 
  <vehicle> 
   <number>180</number> 
   <type>BUS</type> 
 </vehicle> 
 <vehicle> 
   <number>190</number> 
   <type>BUS</type> 
 </vehicle> 
 </station> 
 <station>  
 <vehicle> 
  <number>290</number> 
  <type>BUS</type> 
 </vehicle> 
 <vehicle> 
   <number>380</number> 
   <type>BUS</type> 
  </vehicle> 
 </station> 
<departures>
```

This is the javascript part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: XML_PATH,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                $("#update-target").empty();
                $(xml).find("station").each(function () {
                      $("#update-target").append('<ul>');                        
                        $(this).find("vehicle").each(function () {
                         var number = $(this).find('number').text();
                         var type = $(this).find('type').text();
                            $("#update-target ul").append('<li>' + type + number + '</li>');
                        });
                    });
                    },  
        });
    });
```

On running the above code, i'm not getting any output. Please what is the right way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Your code has a flaw because it always appends to all `<ul>` elements, but that doesn't explain you getting no output at all. Does the XML document you're loading define namespaces?

Comment: The DOm document dosen't have any namespace. What i'm i doing wrong and how can it be done better.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question always appends the current list item to all the `<ul>` elements under `#update-target`, because that's what `#update-target ul` matches.

That does not explain why you're not getting any output at all, but your comment indicates you might want to have a solution for this problem too.

A simple answer is to use the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to only append list items to the last `<ul>` element:

```
$("#update-target ul:last").append("<li>" + type + number + "</li>");
```

To elaborate a little more, you can also try using another paradigm. You want to build DOM elements from the XML markup you receive, which means you want to project some data (XML markup) into other data (DOM elements). In this situation, [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) can be used instead of [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to project data instead of iterating over it, which is closer to functional programming:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_PATH,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $("#update-target").empty()
                               .append($(xml).find("station").map(function() {
                return $("<ul>").append($(this).find("vehicle").map(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    return $("<li>").text($this.find("type").text()
                        + $this.find("number").text());
                }));
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

This way, you don't have to bother matching the current `<ul>` element in the first place, as it becomes part of your current context.

Comment: Hello Frederic, Thank you for your answer. However, that still get it working. There was no display whatever. Have you tried it yourself with the xml list above. Thanks